# JSON instead of View Models

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have recently finished an education within ASP.NET MVC and I need some guidelines and good advices.

If I need data from several models, I have learned to build `View Models`, but recently I heard that instead of `View Models` it's better to use `JSON` objects and return the object as a model to the `View` or just get all the data from the `JSON` object from the `Controller` via `AJAX` calls to the `View` and then show the data with `jQuery` within the `HTML`.

Is this the best way today instead of common `View Models` and refreshing page with POST/GET requests in the URL?

In the `Controller`, do I create a `JSON` object and fill it with data like a list for each `Model` or how does it work?

Comment: The answer to this is, *it depends*. Sometimes it's useful to bind client side sometimes it's not. Entire books have and can be written on this subject

Comment: Moreover, you can combine these two approaches

Comment: @Liam OK, I was just curious to listen what other developer thought about this subject and how they works and I also wanted to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on your need actually. In fact, all your thoughts are correct and could be used accoding to the context needs.

For example; if you need to do straighforward CRUD ops, you can use just a viewmodel and bind to the form. If you need more complex structures, you can create composite view models that contain more than one view model and you can still use the default Model behaviour. 
Moreover, you can use ViewBag/ViewData dictionary objects to pass data to views.

If you need async needs, you can use AJAX (Get/Post) calls

Answer (score 0):

I might be old school but I try to use `view models` as much as possible. What I normally do is to populate the view model in my controller's action method and then pass on this view model to the view:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int brandId)
{
     BrandViewModel model = await brandTask.DetailsAsync(brandId);
     if (model == null)
     {
          throw new HttpException(404, "404");
     }

     return View(model);
}
```

There are times that I will need to first load a page and then populate certain controls with data by returning data in `JSON` format. A while back I worked on a project where I needed to fill a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) with JSON data after the form was loaded:

```
public ActionResult GetApplicationNotes(DataTableParameterViewModel parameterViewModel, int id)
{
     IEnumerable<Note> notes = noteService.FindAllByApplicationId(id);

     var result =
          from note
          in notes
          orderby note.Id descending
          select new[]
          {
               note.Body,
               note.CreatedDate.FormatDate()
          };

     return Json(new
     {
          sEcho = parameterViewModel.sEcho,
          iTotalRecords = notes.Count(),
          iTotalDisplayRecords = notes.Count(),
          aaData = result
     },
     JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It all goes down as to what you need to achieve in your scenario. If I don't need to do anything fancy then I will always use view models first. If I need to update certain parts of a web page then I will do an `AJAX` call and return data in JSON format.

Answer (score -1):

Use web api controller instead of mvc controller.

Mvc controller returns rendered views unless you specified otherwise.
You cannot return object on entity framework because cyclic references thus you should have dtos.

However web api controller will these operations with out dto. plus you can create [query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32971977/492258) then you will receive your jsons

Comment: This is not true. There isn't a great deal more a web api controller can do that an MVC controller can't. They basically use the same technology under the hood. *You cannot return object on entity framework because cyclic references* I'd suggest your EF is set up incorrectly if you have these issues.